# How to draw a frame over an image hovered

Tags: c++, qt

I was thinking a little about title cause I had a problem how to name it. I am programming in Qt and C++ and I can use clearly basic structure. Now I want to do something more efective but I don't know what can be the best solution. So I have an image in main window. How can I solve that:

If I move cursor of my mouse for the specific area of the image then program should drawn yellow frame around this area. If I move mouse to other section of this image then this frame should disappear. In pseudo-code:

```
if(mouse_X >= 100 && mouse_X <=150 && 
     mouse_Y >= 250 && mouse_Y <= 300)
    drawFrame();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Install an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) that does pretty much exactly what your pseudo-code does.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261175/how-to-do-that-when-the-mouse-pointer-hovers-over-a-qpushbutton-then-the-button

Comment: Don't like these dupe targets, they don't answer the question. There doesn't seem to be a canonical _How to install an event filter in Qt_ question with a decent answer.

Comment: You should be a little bit more precise about your current situation, in particular which widget are you using to display that image ? as there could be already a signal ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of solving the issue.

One of them could be to use an event filter as @nwp stated in your question. But it is also necessary to track the mouse movement in your image.

I don't know how you are loading the image, so the next code is just an example supposing that you are loading the image in a `QLabel`. You must to adapt the idea to your own project.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mywindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyWindow myWindow;
    myWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**mywindow.h**

```
#ifndef _MAINWINDOW_H
#define _MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDebug>

class MyWindow: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT    

public:
    MyWindow();
    ~MyWindow();
    bool eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event);

private:
    QLabel *imageLabel;
};

#endif
```

**mywindow.cpp**

```
#include "mywindow.h"
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>

MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
    imageLabel = new QLabel(this);
    imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(":icon"));
    imageLabel->resize(imageLabel->pixmap()->size());
    qDebug() << imageLabel->pixmap()->size();

    imageLabel->setMouseTracking(true);
    imageLabel->installEventFilter(this);
}

MyWindow::~MyWindow()
{
}

bool MyWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == imageLabel && event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove) {
        /*
         * We know the image is 60x60 px.
         */
        QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        if(mouseEvent->x() >= 0 && mouseEvent->x() <=30 &&
           mouseEvent->y() >= 0 && mouseEvent->y() <= 30)
        {
            qDebug() << "drawFrame()";
        } else {
            qDebug() << "!drawFrame()";
        }
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```