# Adding a property to QPushButton in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I am creating an interface using Qt. I added a button and when it comes up with the mouse I see the QLabel and ask for information.(Button will not be clicked) How can I do it.

I wrote following code. But, not view ui->checkout button. I want to view CheckoutButton.

mainwindow.h

```
public:
  explicit PRJSVN(QWidget *parent=0);
  ~PRJSVN();

   bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e);
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
PRJSVN::PRJSVN(QWidget *parent):
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Uİ::PRJSVN)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->CheckoutButton->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool PRJSVN::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if(obj==(QObject*)ui->CheckoutButton)
    {
        if(e->type()==QEvent::Enter)
        {
            ui->label->SetText("Checkout Button");
        }
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj,e);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, do you want to do execute some action on push button click? or do you have some other problem?

Comment: When we move the mouse cursor over the button, for example, "add button" QLabel. @TomConijn

Comment: so when you move your mouse cursor over a button, you want to perform an action? If so the link @dydil posted should help you.

Comment: thank you, I am very new at qt, so give me a code sample @dydil

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 ways to do perform an action on button mouseover.
[See this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261175/how-to-do-that-when-the-mouse-pointer-hovers-over-a-qpushbutton-then-the-button)

The first way is by subclassing the push button and add/emit a new hover signal on the enter event.

The second way is using the event filters, in the widget with the button. When using the event filter approach in the linked question, you should change the event filter function to:

```
bool YourWidget::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if (obj == (QObject*)yourPushButton) {
        if (e->type() == QEvent::Enter)
        {
            // some action on mouseover
        }
    }
    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, e);
}
```

and use the event filter by:

```
yourPushButton->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: I add code, but not view Checkuot button, I want to view Checkoutbutton @TomConijn

Comment: i'm sorry, but i do not understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: 'CheckoutButton' was not declared in this scope

Because your class doesn't have a member called `CheckoutButton`, you class has a member called `ui` and that object has a member called `CheckoutButton`.

See your constructor on how to access it.